# How can I insert objects into a DOORS module via DXL?

Tags: ibm-doors

I read through the [DOORS Reference Manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYQBZ_9.6.0/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/dxl_reference_manual.pdf) but couldn't find a simple insert method. I'm looking to insert an object, which was created within my DXL script, into a module.

I was hoping to find something intuitive like

`insert_object_after(Module m, Object o, string object_identifier)`

which would scan the module for the specified object identifier and insert the object after finding that identifier. Does such a function exist? If not how could I go about performing the action I've described?

Some basic example code would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter „Object management“. Use one of the commands

```
Object create(Module m)
Object create(Object o)
Object create(after(Object o))
Object create(before(Object o))
Object create(below(Object o))
Object create(first(below(Object o)))
Object create(last(below(Object o)))
```

For these functions, you need a variable of type Object. There are several ways to fill such a variable, look at the chapters „Finding objects“ and „Navigation from an object“. Probably the easiest way would be to use the function `Object object(int absno[,Module m])` (with `absno` being the absolute number of the „source“ object. But beware that `object` only works if the current filter allows to navigate to this object, so, if the function "Go To“ from the menu works in your current view with your source object, then `object` should work as well